# How to divide one column with blocks into two?

Tags: javascript, css

I have one container inside which blocks ... everything is lined up in a column. I need to be in two columns. There are 5 blocks in one and 5 blocks in the other. The plugin generates the code for me and I can’t insert my div. How can a javascript be split into two?
blocks can be 10 and 5 and 15 and 20, I need to divide them into two columns

```
<div class="container">

  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>
  <div> < /div>

</div>
```

I want this result

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-first">
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-second">
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
    <div> < /div>
  </div>

</div>

.container{
 display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: how about styling the div container? instead of requesting javascript to split things into 2

Comment: @RamondeVries Grid or Column count does not suit me.
If you have any other suggestions, then tell me

Comment: could you provide the actual plugin outputted html, and a structure of how the code should look like after javascript/css is applied? also i wasn't talking about a grid. i was referring to styling in general. there are more ways of getting div's to go 2 by 2 in a column

Comment: @RamondeVries I updated the question. I want the blocks to be in two columns, half of the blocks in one half in the other

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following styles to the `.container`:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-grid;
}
```

That should split the .container into 2 columns

Ok, since you don't have those classes, you can just have them in the stylesheet you're using, then use Javascript to group them into two -- This is what I mean :-
Have a function that counts the number of divs within the `.container` class:
In this case i'm using jQuery

```
let all = $('.container').children('div').length;
```

Then divide the length by 2 -- This will give the first column.

```
let col1 = all/2;
```

Then round the value up, in case `all` turns out to be an odd number.
If all is 10, then col1 will be 5. If all is 9, col1 will still be 5.

```
col1 = Math.ceil(col1);
```

Now to apply the styles:
This loop adds appropriate styles to the elements and wraps them with another div block that uses the following styles:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let all = $('.container').children('div').length;
  let col1 = all/2;
  col1 = Math.ceil(col1);
  for(let i = 0; i < all; i++){
    if(i < col1){
      $('.container').children('div').eq(i).addClass('col1');
    }
    else {
      $('.container').children('div').eq(i).addClass('col2');
    }
  }
  $('.container').children('.col1').wrapAll('<div class="col-first">');
  $('.container').children('.col2').wrapAll('<div class="col-second">');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-first, .col-second {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

/* These are just additional styles, you dont need these */
.container .elem {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 4px;
}

.col-second .elem.col2 {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

I've also added '.elem' classes so you can see the behavior of the elements

Comment: It's not work in IE11 and it's  spoils me some other element.need some other solution

Comment: Based on your updated question, set .container width to 100% with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` ... then width of both `col-first` and `col-second` to 50%, and have them both with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`

Comment: I do not have these classes (col-first, col-second) ! I want it to look like this, but now it looks like in the first version. I wrote how simple it should look approximately. It says "I want "

Comment: View my edited answer above

Answer (score 1):

i've made a code that loops through the children of a div, slices it in half and puts the first half in a div and the second half in another div, hope this helps

```js
//here we calculate the length of the divs inside the container, and with Math.ceil we make sure we don't get .5 values
let length = Math.ceil($(".container").children().length /2);
//save the current html before we add div's
let children = $(".container").children();
//after the calculation we add the container divs for the first and second half of the items
$(".container").append("<div class='first-half half'></div><div class='second-half half'></div>");

//here we add the last half to the last half div
$(children).slice(length).appendTo(".second-half");
//and the first half
$(children).slice(0, length).appendTo(".first-half");
```

```css
.container{
  background: blue;
  height: fit-content;
}
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first-half{
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div>this should be in the first half </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> this in the second</div>

</div>
```

don't mind the css. just look at the html output